$F(x)+F(\frac{1} {x})=\frac{3}{2}$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$
Let  $f:(0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ $f(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x+1}$
Given that $F(1)=\frac{1}{2
}$ .I am asked to solve the equation $F(x)+F(\frac{1}
{x})=\frac{3}{2}$ for $x>0$ where $F$ is a function $F : (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in (0,+\infty),F'(x)=f(x)$.
I have already found that $f$ has exactly one critical point somewhere in $(1,2)$ in which there is a local maxima with value $f(x_0)=\frac{1}{x_0}$
I tried to let $g(x)=F(x)+F(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{3}{2}$
taking the derivative of it we get $g'(x)=f(x)-\frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}$ which simplifies to $g'(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x}$
I then found that $g'<0 $ when $0<x<1$ and $g'>0$ when $x>1$ and $g$ is continuous so
it is decreasing for $x \in (0,1]
$ and it is increasing for $x \in[1,+\infty)$
and thats where I hit a dead-end because I know nothing else about $F$  and the only piece of information I haven't used yet is that $f$ has only one critical point but I can figure out how will that be useful. Any help would be appreciated !
Edit: when I use "$\log$" I'm referring to the natural logarithm

Antiderivatives are only defined up to an arbitrary additive constant, so the question doesn't seem to make sense. Why $F(1)=\frac12$?

@AnneBauval That's exactly what I thought at first but since we know $F(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ I am "assuming" the solution can be worked out

How do you know that? You didn't share it in the problem statement. (See update at the end of my first comment)

I did , but it's in the end of the second sentence maybe you skipped over it.

@StéphaneJaouen Yes I did , thanks for pointing it out .

@StéphaneJaouen It sadly isn't , $F(1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Why ? Could you explain ?

@AntonyTheo can you show how you found $F(1)=\frac12$? It looks like you are missing part of the question (perhaps you're given a value of $F$?)

Sorry It was given that $F(1)=\frac{1}{2
}$ I misplaced it in my original post

Let's look at the form $p(x)=F(x)+F\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.
We have
$$\begin{align}p'(x)&=f(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
&=\frac{\log x}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\frac{\log x}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{\log x}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=\frac{\log x}{x+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
&=\frac{\log x}{x}\end{align}$$
So
$$p(x)=\frac12 \left(\log x\right)^2+C$$
Now, since $F(1)=\frac12$, $p(1)=1$ and so $C=1$.
So we have to solve
$$\frac12 \left(\log x\right)^2+1=\frac32$$
which leads to $x=e$ or $x=\frac{1}{e}$.
